# Converting byte array or String value to float in P5.js (javascript based)

Tags: javascript, p5.js, data-conversion

**I have been successful in getting serial data in P5.js sketch** using this - GitHub - p5-serial/p5.serialport: Serial Port API and Server for p5.js library as either byte array or string values.

When I tried converting string to float type using float() – I get a lot of NaN values which shouldn’t be coming since data is numerical.

Alternatively, I then tried getting data from serial port as byte array. **I can’t find a way to convert this array to my original float value in P5.js.**

**Any ideas on how to convert byte array to float or avoid getting NaN when converting string to float?**

Appreciate your time and help. Thanks.

Codes I have tried for conversion:

1. From String to float, I used

   ```
   let incomingData;

   let dataValue;

   incomingData = serial.readStringUntil('\n');

   dataValue = float(incomingData);  //standard method in P5.js -- returns NaN values
   ```

I also tried parseFloat() -- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-parsefloat-function/

```
  dataValue = parseFloat(incomingData);
  //again returns maximum values as NaN
```

2. From byte array to float

   ```
   let incomingBytes = [];

   let dataValue;

   incomingBytes = serial.readBytesUntil('\n');

   dataValue = dataView.getFloat64(bytebuffer); 
   // This javascript method is not supported by P5.js it seems
   ```

[image: original data in arduino]
[image: string data in P5.js]
[image: NaN after converting to float]
[image: array of converted values - a lot of NaN]
[image: array of string data without conversion]

Comment: add snippet of your array you are trying to convert. maybe it will help.

Comment: I have updated the post with code snippets and images. Let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you do: `incomingData = serial.readStringUntil('\n').trim();` ?

Comment: I have tried trimming; same results. I get NaN for string to float.

Comment: I have shared a new picture -- shows array of 1000  converted values (string to float) -- maximum values return NaN.

Comment: May you post picture of array without converting it?

Comment: Okay, there are some empty strings coming -- so then the serial data is not coming correctly after all. Thanks. I will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the last image, there were empty strings or null values coming. I just had to put a check for it before doing the conversion.

Thanks to all the commenters.

```
 let incomingData;                    //incoming serial value is stored in this variable

 let temparray = [1000];              //temporary array used in updating final array

 let plot_from_here = [1000];         //final array of values to plot
 function setup(){}
 function draw(){}

 function serialEvent() {

  if(serial.available()>0){

   incomingData = serial.readStringUntil('\n');    //read string until next line

    if(incomingData != ""){

     incomingData = trim(incomingData);            //trim white spaces

     arrayCopy(temparray,0, temparray,1,999);      //Copy value from index 0 to index 1

     temparray[0]= float(incomingData);            //Update index 0 of temparray for the incoming value -- the value is converted to float from string type

     plot_from_here = temparray;                   //update values in final array

    print(plot_from_here);

     }
   }
  }
```